# Scheduling an email to be sent 24 hours from now?

Tags: iphone, xcode, email, ios5, uilocalnotification

I would like my app to be able to send a reminder email (or text) at various points in the future. I was thinking this might be doable with local notifications but now I am not seeing how. Any advice on a good strategy for making this happen? More details:

I am building an iPhone app, using Xcode.  It is a small reminder app that will remind you to do something after a user-specified number of hours have passed.  So you could set a reminder for yourself to TiVo the donkey races in 11 hours, for example, and the app would send out that reminder via email.  I was hoping to keep the whole process within the phone. So the app would register an event (like a local notification) and use the Mail app to send the email.

If I have to go the server route I can always set up cron jobs but I am hoping to avoid that, because then I need to worry about scaling to many users. AN iMessage or a tweet might be a good alternative if that is more realistic.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What programming language are you talking about? And is the application running all the time? Or are you interacting with a server? A few more details would be nice.

Comment: Using which programming language ?

Comment: what mail-service/server you use would be a start. Some of them offer timed/delay of mails to send.

Comment: Ha! Shame on me! I left out every single detail. Funny how you can get so wrapped up in your project that you assume everyone else is doing the same thing. The app is an iPhone app, written in cocoa/ objective c and I was hoping the email would be from the user of the app, or the owner of the iPhone, using the mail app on the phone itself. If I have to use a server, then the whole idea of the app goes out the window :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research (and I hope that someday I discover I am wrong) there is no way to schedule an email or a text or a tweet or any other communication for the future. One can use Local Notifications, but the available actions for this are to display a message on the device and play a sound. That's it. The root issue is that you cannot execute code without your app being in the foreground and active. If anyone thinks I am wrong about this please chime in!